# Hibernate bulk operations migrate databases

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I wrote a small executable jar using Spring & Spring Data JPA to migrate data from a database, converting objects from original database (throught several tables) to valid objects for the new database and then insert the new objects in new database.

Problem is : I process a large amount of data (200 000) and doing my insert one by one is really time consuming (1hr, all the time is spent for the INSERT operations which happen after validating/transforming incoming data, it is not spent for the retrieval from original database nor validation/conversion).

I already had suggestions about it :

- [Edit because i didn't explain it well] As I am doing a
  extract-validate-transform-insert, do my insert (which are valid
  because they are verified first) X objects by X objects (instead of
  inserting it one by one). *That is the suggestion from the frist
  answer : tried it but that not so efficient, stil time consuming.*
- Instead of saving directly in database, save the insert into a .sql file and then import the file directly in database. But how to translate myDao.save() to a final SQL output and then write it to a file.
- Use Talend : know as probably the best way, but too long to re-do everything. I'd like to find a way using java  and refactor my jar.
- Other ideas ?

Note : one important point is that if one valisation fails I want to continue to process other data, I only log an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should pause and think for a minute: what could cause an error when inserting your data into the database? Short of "your database is hosed", there are two posibilities:

1. There is a bug in your code;
2. The data coming in is bad.

If you have a bug in your code, you would be better of if all your data load is reverted. You will get another chance to transfer data after you fix your code.

If the data coming in is bad, or is suspected bad, you should add a step for validating your data. So, your process workflow might look like this: Extract --> Validate --> Transform --> Load. If the incoming data is invalid, write it into the log or load into a separate table for erroneous data.

You should keep all your process run in the same transaction, using the same Hibernate session. Keeping all 200K reords in memory would be pushing it. I suggest using batching (see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html). In two words, after a predetermined number of records, say 1000, flush and clear your Hibernate session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, currently : 
-> Errors : data is bad (verified).
-> I already do the extract, validate,  transform, load
-> Validate step : bad incoming data creates a log, then I go to next validate
-> I was mistaken in my original post, i'm going to edit it right now. So I can safely process my insert using X objects and flush, i'll see what it does.
- Hibernate batching style is still too long.

-> Let try to check my other guess : can i write it to a .sql file so that it can be loaded later (using database sql file load is faster that inserting objects)

Comment: @Steph0: I am much more familiar with Oracle and PostgreSQL than with MySQL. From my first glance at the MySQL documentation, looks like LOAD DATA INFILE should fit the bill, but I understand that MySQL can be configured to use different data engines and that command is not necesserely universally applicable.